# I am getting error message

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Getting error : **syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)**
 my code is :

```
 @extends('layouts.masters.main')
        @section('page-content')

        <div class="container">

         @include('layouts.partials.nav')

         {!! Form::open(['route' => 'post_register', 'id' => 'registration-form']) !!}

             {!! Form::label('name', 'Full Name') !!}
        {!! Form::text('name', null, ['id' => 'name', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Full Name', 'required']) !!}

         {!! Form::label('email', 'Email Address') !!}
         {!! Form::email('email',null,['id' => 'email', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Email Address', 'required']) !!}


         {!! Form::label('password', 'password') !!}
         {!! Form::password('password',['id' => 'password', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'password', 'required']) !!}

         {!! Form::button('Register','class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block', 'type' => 'submit')!!}
         {!! Form::close() !!}


        </div> <!-- /container -->
        @stop
```

please help ... i can't uderstand where i do the mistake in this code

Answer (score 1):

When you use "=>" the content should be inside an array (class, type, etc..)

So, try this;

```
{!! Form::button('Register', ['class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block', 'type' => 'submit']) !!}
```

Comment: Thank you so much peter it's now fix

Comment: There is another one problem can you help me ?? i am not getting my css class over this page how can i get the css on this page

Comment: Yes! How do you calling the CSS in master page?

Comment: <html lang="en">
  <head>
    
   
    
 

  
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="navbar-static-top.css" rel="stylesheet">

     
     
  </head>
  <body>

Comment: css call on home page like public page but not in register page

Comment: Change to: {{ asset( 'css/bootstrap.min.css' ) }} and repeat for this code for the others.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107997/discussion-between-navnit-mishra-and-peter).